# Is it acceptable to ask questions regarding originality of a plot on Stack Exchange?

Tags: support

I got an idea for a novel. I want to make sure that this idea is truly new.

Is it acceptable to post questions like "has there been a book/movie/TV show with this plot?" on [literature.stackexchange.com](https://literature.stackexchange.com/) and [movies.stackexchange.com](https://movies.stackexchange.com)? If yes, what tags should I use for the question?

In the past I saw many posts on https://movies.stackexchange.com where someone would describe the plot and then ask the community to identify this movie. I want to do something similar -- if there is no movie/book with a similar plot, then my idea is truly new.

Comment: FYI: People do not read books because they are "truly new"; they read them because they are *interesting*, "new" or not. If the only reason you can think of for why someone would want to read your story is that it is "truly new", then you're not going to be successful with it. Focus on making a good story, and let "truly new" sort itself out.

Comment: @NicolBolas but an original plot/storyline has its place, although I agree it's the writing that counts most. Even the most banal topic, a spring day, can become Art with the right pen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, "has there been [...]" is considered as an open-ended list-question and it is discouraged due to the nature of Stack Exchange preferring objective answers. (Some sites have an exception, but irrelevant for this case)

However, your question can be relatively reworded as an objective question, such as "what is the first occurrence of [...]", and based on existing questions on some sites:

- **Movies & TV** has ['cinema-history'](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cinema-history) and ['first-appearance'](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-appearance) tags
- **Literature** has ['history-of-literature'](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of-literature) tag
- **Science Fiction & Fantasy** has ['history-of'](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of) tag
- **Anime & Manga** has ['anime-history'](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-history) tag.

You also possibly need to break your plot to a much smaller and specific plot to prevent your question being too broad.

Comment: Yeah, I blamed myself for my hasty close-vote.